# How to limit or exclude special character or regular expressions in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I ask user to enter a motif for search with standard keyboard input.

```
do {
    print "Enter a motif to search for: ";
    $motif = <STDIN>;
    chomp $motif;
    if ( $protein =~ /$motif/ ) {
        print "I found it!\n\n";
    } else {
        print "I couldn\'t find it.\n\n";
    }
} until ( $motif =~ /^\s*$/ );
```

The problem is that if user types in a regular expression or special character set, such as "TTG**", the program run into error:

```
Enter a motif to search for: TTG**
Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/DE** <-- HERE / at example_
5-3.txt line 35, <STDIN> line 9.
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? It's doing what it says on the tin - if you give it a bad regex, it doesn't work. Are you trying to: a) prevent people using regex, b) trap errors if they do use a bad regex or c) actually match the text as a literal?

Comment: Hi! Both (a) and (b). Trying to block certain regex mainly, and also tryig to avoid errors if they use the allowed ones in bad form

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a regex, use [index](http://p3rl.org/index)

```
if (-1 != index $protein, $motif) {
```

Or, quote the regex:

```
if ($protein =~ /\Q$motif/) {
```

Comment: Definitely don't use a regex in this case! It would be too slow if they have many motifs, and a motif is *always* a simple short string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to trap broken regexes - you can:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $broken_re = '.**';
eval { qr/$broken_re/; };

print "Proceeding...\n";
print "Eval broke: $@\n" if $@;;
```

Thus you can trap anything that just doesn't work.

Limiting regular expressions though, is considerably harder. Because you ... pretty much have to regex your regex, and that's a road to insanity. However, you can make use of e.g. `quotameta` if you want to escape *all* special characters, or e.g. `\Q` and `\E` to escape the metachars.

But you could *perhaps* whitelist elements in your regex, but I'd be wary of that - a partially working/partially broken regex engine, was difficult.